# Get list of users from Domino Directory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-domino

I would like to create a simple drop down containing all the users in our Domino Directory (names.nsf) - we where using a Dojo Namepicker from the ExtLib but where having multiple problems with our Huawei phones, but thats a tale for another time :o) - no matter what I try I am just getting back an empty list. Here is the XPages code:

```
                 <xp:comboBox value="#{document1.betreuerIn}" style="width:350px"
                    id="comboBox1" required="true" defaultValue="#{javascript:sessionScope._stdCommonUserName}">
                    <xp:selectItems>
                       <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:allPeople()}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:selectItems>
                 </xp:comboBox>
```

and here the function allPeople:

```
var mydb = new Array (@DbName()[0], "names.nsf");
var myPeople = new Array (@DbColumn(mydb, "($VIMPeople)", 1));
return myPeople;
```

or

```
var mydb = new Array (@DbName()[0], "names.nsf");
return @DbColumn(mydb, "($VIMPeople", 1);
```

I am always getting an empty list back. mydb contains a server and the names.nsf database. The view ($VIMPeople) exists in the Domino Directory.

According to this: http://xpageswiki.com/apps/wiki-xpages/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_DbColumn_and_DbLookup it should work?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the ACL of Names.nsf to make sure that 1. Anonymous or your authenticated user has Reader or higher access and 2. The advanced tab allows reader or higher access from the browsers.

Comment: You also might consider to use a applicationScope bean that caches the result. People in your directory don't change that often. We did one that had a reset function admins would use when they updated people

Comment: I am manager of the names DB (and Anonymous has Reader access), Will cache result as soon as I get something Stephan :)

Comment: How many documents do you have in the view?
Because one of the possible options that you are getting an empty list is that you are over the limit of 64K. If so maybe this will help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264890/how-to-avoid-the-64k-limit-when-retrieving-data-from-a-view-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264890/how-to-avoid-the-64k-limit-when-retrieving-data-from-a-view-column)

Comment: In addition to @Newbs: what is "Maximum internet access" in NAB ACL?